# MPMoviePlayerController reuse in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, reuseidentifier

I am working on creating a table where each cell has a play button and a MPMoviePlayerController. It is setup so that I have custom UITableViewCell class that loads a .xib. Just to make sure the cells are being reused correctly, I have the tableView Controller set a number for the button title (whatever the indexpath.row is). This displays correctly, but when I play one of the cell's videos and scroll down quickly it appears again in another cell. How can I resolve this?